# What does the console record "... kernel[0]: AppName[a number] Unable to quarantine: 1" mean?

Tags: cocoa, console, sandbox, appstore-sandbox, osx-gatekeeper

Lately, I have been trying to sandbox one of my Cocoa apps.

Other things are fine, except that I keep getting the information as in the title in the console for my app.

The record seems to appear at the moment of my file read/write operation. But those operations all succeeded.

What does this record mean? Can I afford to ignore it?

Comment: Depends: What kind of files do you read/write? Quarantine usually means that GateKeeper is involved. Where are the files you read/write?

Comment: Most of the files are AppleScript. I have realized that those files have "com.apple.quarantine" in their extended attributes, is that probably where all this stems from?

Answer (score 0):

as you are writing executable files, Gatekeeper has it's eye on it. because the files come from a trusted source (the signed and sandboxed app) you can ignore these messages. see [documentation on sandboxing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW9)

Comment: Thanks for the info, tertin. My understanding of the quarantine attribute so far is that it is for OS X to mark files it thinks have potential danger. I will assume that I can ignore the records in the console I had encountered. Maybe I will figure out the essential cause for it someday when I understand it better.